# Make email authentication case insensitive in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, authentication

I use the default email authentication in Laravel 5.7.3 (just updated from 5.4) with a sqlite DB. At login my email address gets validated case sensitive which is not what I want. It should be allowed to login with "JohnDoe@foobar.com" as well as "johndoe@foobar.com".

I've tried to add an accessor at my user model to always lowercase the database value.

```
public function getEmailAttribute($value) {
    return strtolower($value);
}
```

But this one doesn't seem to be used by Auth at all. Additionally I don't know where to change the user input in the incomming request to lower case.

Is there a simple config case sensitive switch? Or where do I need to change/add scripts?

Thanks for your support
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your accessor should be fine, but you should make sure that you also lowercase the given value, e.g. In your controller:

Assuming that you're using the default LoginController shipped from Laravel:
I overwrote the `credentials` method from `AuthenticatesUsers` in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        $this->username() => strtolower($request->get($this->username())),
        "password" => $request->get("password")
    ];

    return $credentials;
}
```

This works fine, when all emails stored in the database are already stored all-lowercase. If you're starting from scratch you can enforce the emails to be stored lowercase by default. Just implement the following mutator in your `App\User`:

```
public function setEmailAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

If you have stored mixed-case email already, you can update all emails to lowercase emails using this query:

```
UPDATE users SET email = LOWER(email);
```

But this still feels kind of incomplete and you maybe don't want to manipulate your data this way. I am pretty much sure that there are more possibilities to make this happen but unfortunately I am not able to dig into this further for now. However my next attempt would be to extend/write a custom UserProvider.

Comment: I use the default Laravel authentication and don't have my own controller for this. (IMHO this is done in the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php right?) Does this mean, I need to create my own controller for this? This looks so complicated for such a simple task. (typical newbie issue...)

Comment: As far as I remember new laravel projects are always shipped with an `AuthController`, please have a look into `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`. You should find an `AuthController` there, and *yes* this controller is using the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. Knowing this you may overwrite the trait-methods in your `AuthController` to enable your own logic. If you dont want to overwrite the whole `login` method, you can simply overwrite `credentials`, this should be enough to make your modifications.

Comment: I've found the `LoginController` in `Controllers/Auth` which uses the `AuthenticateUsers` trait. I've added an `attemptLogin` function there ovewriting the one from `LoginController` and this seems to work for the request part but looks like a hack. The accessor still doesn't seem to be used. Should `$this->guard()->user()` from `AuthenticatesUsers` uses the accessor?

Comment: @kirschkern I just tried to authenticate on a fresh laravel 5.7 installation (but I am using mysql) and the case-insensitive login works for me out of the box, don't even need to create accessor nor overwrite methods on AuthenticatesUsers trait. Seems like something else is your issue, might be caused by update from 5.4 to 5.7

Comment: Thanks for the test and feedback. The problem existed before the update. I finally updated because I thought it might resolve the issue. Anyway good to know that the default behaviour is as expected. I allready wondered why only I have that problem. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Probably the different unicode handling of SQLite and MySQL is the cause. I've just found this one: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18 To my understanding this means: While MySQL is case-insensitive by default, SQLite is not when using Unicode.

Comment: I agree, just changed to sqlite and reproduced your issue. Let me take a look, will update my answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: wow, thanks! For now I've overwritten the `attemptLogin` function in my LoginController where I added a `$request["email"] = strtolower($request["email"]);`. Additionally when creating the user in my UserController I added this: `$user = new User(); $user->email = strtolower($email); $user->save();` This should do the trick.

Comment: As mentioned earlier I think that its enough to overwrite `credentials` method.  In addition you can also create a Mutator to always store email in lowercase instead of performing this in your controller. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call getEmailAttribute(/*your email here*/)
before login and signup like this

```
$request->email = getEmailAttribute($request->get('email'));
```